# 3x3 table with fixed corners

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make a frame in this case a 3x3 table (using CSS) keeping the corners fixed in size and making the rest of the table stretch according to the "cell" in the interior. Using the classic tables it would have probably took me no more than 10 minutes but because I've encountered problems with tables in the past *cough *cough IE *cough I've decided to try the CSS way using div-s and span-s but for some reason it just doesn't show right.

Can I have some hints?

Comment: Well, it seems pretty straightforward; what problem(s) are you having?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried but just doesn't quite work right?

Comment: The HTML and CSS you have so far would probably give us a good foundation to try and fix it.  By the way, what's the goal?  There might be a simpler way to accomplish this without all the containers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question right, but I *think* you're just looking for `<div>`s with 33% width, with a clearing `<br />` after every three (or you could keep each row in a containing div of it's own):

CSS:

```
  .col {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
  }

  /* color columns for clarity */
  .odd {
    background-color: #999;
  }

  .even {
    background-color: #666;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col odd">1</div>
<div class="col even">2</div>
<div class="col odd">3</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
<div class="col even">4</div>
<div class="col odd">5</div>
<div class="col even">6</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
<div class="col odd">7</div>
<div class="col even">8</div>
<div class="col odd">9</div>
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I made a picture to represent what I tried to do:http://i54.tinypic.com/2hyjwub.png   If there is a way to do this through divs and spans and still be viewable in ie6-7  then I'm sure it would be kind of complicated. I'm trying to make custom frames for images of different sizes .

Comment: Custom frames for images? So, when you say 3x3 grid, you mean 8 "cells" of framing images, and one center "cell" that contains the image you want to frame? Am I understanding you right now?

Comment: yes... exactly! Here's my table version(if I don't find a good css version, I'll stick with this one): http://muddypaw.byethost15.com/frame.php

Comment: @Muddy Paw: I don't think there's an easy way to do this with *dynamic* content (e.g. text that is allowed to expand in any direction). If the content you're framing was static (i.e. if it had explicit height and width) then you could do this pretty easily. I think if you need this now, you're probably going to have to stick to the tables, and wait for browsers to start implementing the CSS3 border-image property. I'll keep looking for a solution, but it doesn't look promising. You should edit your question to reflect the updated info you've given me, in case someone else can help.